# How can I use join on columns with different names?

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use join from the plyr library, but my columns have different names.  I am joining by country.  One has the word Country and the other country (differing in case).

The command

```
foo <- join(ie, geo, by="Country")
```

gives me this error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(x, by) : undefined columns selected

How can I modify the by parameter to join the two different column names?

Comment: With the base R `merge` function you can choose `by.x` and `by.y` or rename your columns and continue to use `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation this does not seem to be possible. As pointed out in the comment the base function `merge` will handle this with `by.x = "Country"` and `by.y = "country"`, but merge is quite slow. I think the best option is to rename one of the columns (and change the name back after the join if you need to).

Also consider using the join functions from `dplyr` which are faster than those in `plyr`, for example

```
> system.time(x<-inner_join(baseball, baseball, by = "id"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.037   0.000   0.037 
> system.time(x<-join(baseball, baseball, by = "id"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.943   0.002   0.945 
>
```